# Names of rooms for a Revolutionary war/Early America era?

Tags: word-usage

I'm working on a story set in the Revolution/Early America era, and the family in the story is an upperclass family, with a mansion in the south.

I've heard Drawing room, Parlor, Sitting room, and many others to describe a living room, but I'm not sure the right one to use without saying 'living room' which is what I want to avoid.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Those are all different things.  Pick the one that is right in your situation.

Comment: http://numberonelondon.net/2017/09/the-name-of-the-room-when-is-a-saloon-not-a-saloon/

Comment: Why do you want to avoid *living room*?